# How to get indexPath in cell class?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I'm trying to get the indexPath of a tableView cell in the cell class.
I've got a collectionView inside the table view cells and I'm trying to make label inside the collectionView cell show the indexPath.row of the tableView cell that particular collectionView in.

Currently i have

```
var indexPathForCell: indexPath
```

in my cell class.

Then in the tableView class i have this in `cellForRowAt indexpath`

```
cell.indexpathForCell = indexPath  
lbl.text = String(indexPathForCell.row)
```

If there is "3" or fewer tableView cells this works but if theres more then the 4th row then shows "0" as the indexPathForcell.row, and as I scroll in the collectionView the numbers then chnage from "0" to "3" and even show "1". Each cell then shows a different number as i scroll.

Comment: Why show the indexPath.row value? If you need to show the count, can't you make use of the model you use to populate data?

Comment: Each tableView cell is a sub-category in the app. The tableView indexPath.row tell the collectionView which sub-category it is and then it can load data from Firebase for the collection view cells etc. @RakshithNandish

Comment: Great, have a value in your collectionView cell, when you set up the tableview, using your model array count, set the value of the collectionview cell. Then based on that value run your logic when populating the collectionview.

Comment: There is no reason a cell needs to know its own current index path. If you believe it does then you are doing it incorrectly.

Comment: I’ve got tabs at the top with categories, each category has a tableView with a collectionView in each cell. Each tableView cell is a subcategory. The tableView indexPath.row tells the collectionView which subcategory to display and the collectionView indexPath.row tells the collectionView cell which restaurant data to load from Firebase. What would be a more correct method? (still new to coding) @rmaddy

Comment: Currently in Firebase I have restaurant data following this format 0-1-2  (eg) ”0” is the category number, the top bar gives this as an index Int, the “1” is the subcategory num which would be the indexPath.row of the tableView, then “2” is the restaurant number which is the indexPath.row of the collectionView. Using this method made it easier to keep track of everything. @rmaddy

Answer (score 0):

a simple solution for that is, in your viewController inside the collection cellForItemAt method gives the cell a tag like

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SignupSelectCourseCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! SignupSelectCourseCollectionViewCell

    cell.tag = indexPath.row

    return cell
}
```

and now you can access tag property in cell class like

```
    override var isSelected: Bool {
didSet {

    let indexPathRow = self.tag
 }
}
```